# Angular 12 - save and retrieve time of video

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

I am trying to save and retreive time range for the video. All works well except when i click on the time it is not calculating accurately. If i have saved the beginning of the time, when i click on the time it is taking me to the end of the video. Please help.

Component :

```
`
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer: ElementRef | undefined;
  newComment: string = '';
  comments: any[] = [];
  highlightedTimeRange: { start: number, end: number } | null = null;
  currentProgress: number = 0;
  
  isDragging: boolean = false;
  selectionStart: number | null = null;
  selectionEnd: number | null = null;
   // Properties to store the start and end times of the selected time range
   savedStartTime: number | null = null;
   savedEndTime: number | null = null;
    // Array to store comments with their associated time ranges
  commentsArr: { start: number, end: number, text: string, user: string }[] = [];
  videoDuration: number = 0; // Initialize with '0:00' for now
  progressBarWidth: number = 0;


  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.onTimeUpdate.bind(this));
  }

  annotateTimeSegment() {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    videoElement.pause();
  }

  formatDuration(seconds: number): string {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    return `${minutes}:${remainingSeconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }
  

   // Method to handle the drag event
   onProgressBarDrag(event: MouseEvent) {
    debugger;
    const progressBar = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.progress-bar');
    const progressBarRect = progressBar.getBoundingClientRect();
    const progressBarWidth = progressBar.offsetWidth;
    const offsetX = event.clientX - progressBarRect.left;
    const newPosition = (offsetX / progressBarWidth) * 100;

    if (this.isDragging) {
      // Restrict within 0-100 range and set selectionStart and selectionEnd accordingly
      this.selectionStart = this.selectionStart === null ? newPosition : Math.min(this.selectionStart, newPosition);
      this.selectionEnd = Math.max(this.selectionStart, newPosition);
    }
  }

  // Method to seek to a specific position in the video
  seekToPosition(position: number) {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    const newTime = (position / 100) * this.videoDuration;
    videoElement.currentTime = newTime;
  }
  

  onProgressBarClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    const progressBar = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.progress-bar');
    const progressBarRect = progressBar.getBoundingClientRect();
    const progressBarWidth = progressBar.offsetWidth;
    const offsetX = event.clientX - progressBarRect.left;
    const newPosition = (offsetX / progressBarWidth) * 100;

    // Seek to the clicked position
    this.seekToPosition(newPosition);
  }

  addCommentForSelection() {
    debugger;
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    const duration = videoElement.duration;

    if (this.selectionStart !== null && this.selectionEnd !== null) {
      const start = (this.selectionStart / 100) * duration;
      const end = (this.selectionEnd / 100) * duration;

      const comment = {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        text: this.newComment,
        user: 'shirish'
      };

      this.comments.push(comment);
      this.newComment = ''; // Clear the comment input field
    }
  }

  
  addComment() {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    const currentTime = videoElement.currentTime;
    const comment = {
      time: currentTime,
      text: this.newComment,
      user: 'bhummas'
    };
    this.comments.push(comment); // Store the comment in the array
    this.newComment = ''; // Clear the comment input field
    videoElement.play(); // Resume video playback
  }

  goToTime(time: number) {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    videoElement.currentTime = time;
    videoElement.pause();
  }

  goToTimeTimeRange(time: number) {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    const middleTime = (this.savedStartTime + this.savedEndTime) / 2;
  
    // Ensure the middleTime is within the valid range
    const currentTime = Math.max(Math.min(middleTime, videoElement.duration), 0);
    videoElement.currentTime = currentTime;
    videoElement.pause(); // Ensure the video resumes playback after seeking
  }
  
  
  
  
  onTimeUpdate() {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    if (videoElement) {
      const currentTime = videoElement.currentTime;
      const duration = videoElement.duration;
      this.currentProgress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
      this.videoDuration = duration; // Store the duration in seconds
    }
  }
  
  
  

  onMetadataLoaded() {
    const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
    this.videoDuration = videoElement.duration;
    this.currentProgress = 0; // Reset currentProgress when video metadata is loaded
  
    const progressBar = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.progress-bar');
    this.progressBarWidth = progressBar.offsetWidth; // Store the progress bar width
  
    // Set the initial progress bar width based on the video's duration
    progressBar.style.width = `${this.progressBarWidth}px`;
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  

   // Method to handle the "Save" button click event
 // Method to handle the "Save" button click event
 onSaveTimeRange() {
  if (this.selectionStart !== null && this.selectionEnd !== null) {
    this.savedStartTime = this.selectionStart;
    this.savedEndTime = this.selectionEnd;

    const comment = {
      start: this.savedStartTime,
      end: this.savedEndTime,
      text: this.newComment,
      user: 'shirish'
    };
  
    this.commentsArr.push(comment);
    this.selectionStart = null;
    this.selectionEnd = null;

  }


}
  
isHighlightedTimeRange(start: number, end: number): boolean {
  return this.savedStartTime !== null && this.savedEndTime !== null &&
    this.savedStartTime === start && this.savedEndTime === end;
}
  
}`
```

html

```
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <video #videoPlayer controls (timeupdate)="onTimeUpdate()"  (loadedmetadata)="onMetadataLoaded()">
      <source src="assets/test1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="progress-bar"
         (mousedown)="isDragging = true; onProgressBarDrag($event)"
         (mousemove)="isDragging && onProgressBarDrag($event)"
         (mouseup)="isDragging = false"
    >
      <div class="progress" [style.width.%]="currentProgress"></div>
      <div class="selection" [style.left.%]="selectionStart" [style.width.%]="selectionEnd - selectionStart"
           [class.highlighted]="isHighlightedTimeRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd)"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comments-container">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of comments" (click)="goToTime(comment.time)">
      <p>{{ comment.user }} - {{ comment.text }} ({{ comment.time }}s)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
  <button (click)="annotateTimeSegment()">Annotate Time Segment</button>
  <div class="add-comment">
    <label for="comment"> Comment:</label>
    <input type="text" id="comment" [(ngModel)]="newComment" placeholder="Enter your comment">
    <button (click)="addCommentForSelection()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="onSaveTimeRange()">Save Time Range</button>
<p *ngIf="savedStartTime !== null && savedEndTime !== null">
  Saved Time Range: {{ savedStartTime }}s - {{ savedEndTime }}s
</p>

<div class="comments-container">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArr" (click)="goToTimeTimeRange(comment.start)">
    <p>{{ comment.user }} - {{ comment.text }} ({{ comment.start }}s - {{ comment.end }}s)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```